# Windows Folder Redirection causes application crash

Tags: group-policy, folder-redirection

An application I support (Windows) writes log fie and other data to a users home folder %UserDocuments%.

A new customer has GPO Folder Redirection, which maps the above folder to a server drive.

What we see when the app runs is that it crashes after a short while.

In looking for the log file, I searched using Windows Explorer and found that in Explorer, the folder seemed to disappear from view after a second or so.

I hadn't seen this before, but it was later revealed to me that this in fact was Folder Redirection.

So, what happens is the app starts and opens file handles with the folder, but then when Folder Redirection asserts its workings, the files disappear, and the the file handles become invalid, causing a crash (I think).

Now, we can look at the application and see if we can cater for this, but this will cause a problem if saving a large application data document. But is there anything in the Folder Redirection set up that we might be able to tweak to stop this happening?